# Testing for .on() with a .bind() fallback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am working on a site that is currently using... 
[image: jquery version 1.2.6]

So while binding events, how would I test for [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) while falling back to [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)? A site upgrade is in the works eventually, but not before I finish the task that I'm currently working on.

**Update**: Based on the feedback below, I'm using the following:

```
if (typeof $.fn.on !== "function") {
    $.fn.on = $.fn.bind;
}
if (typeof $.fn.off !== "function") {
    $.fn.off = $.fn.unbind;
}
```

Comment: I would just use .bind, .bind will also work in 1.9.1

Comment: I wonder if this would work: `function hasOn() { return typeof $().on !== 'undefined'; }`

Comment: @RickViscomi $.fn.on would be safer, i think some versions of jQuery didn't return an empty jQuery object with `$()`

Comment: Thanks @KevinB & @RickViscomi I think I will use something like that to test for `.on()` then if it doesn't exist, I'll assign `.bind()` to it like @MartinJespersen has below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pollyfill file that did something like:

```
$.fn.on = $.fn.bind;
$.fn.off = $.fn.unbind;
```

but probably a little more clever than what i have written above, and then take out that file when you upgrade jQuery down the line

Comment: Combined with Kevin and Rick's suggestions above, this will work just fine. Thanks.